# can no longer connect to postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql

I wanted to free up some space in my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) VM, so I removed previous versions of postgresql (I had versions 9.4, 9.5 and 10.5) to remain with version 10.5 only.

So I ran the command `sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.*`
Now, I have only version 10.5. Problem is, I can no longer connect to my databases using PGAdmin, also, all my C  programs connecting to postgres DB can no longer connect!

I tried looking up on internet, modified files
`pg_hba.conf`  and `postgresql.conf` to allow all connections from port 5432, and even reopenned port 5432, still nothing!

On command line, I can connect to my databases using:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
....
```

Comment: Is it definitely running? Can you see it bound to port 5432 on `netstat -anp` ? If you had multiple postgresql instances did it get shifted to a different port?

Comment: This question does not belong on StackOverflow. You might be looking for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.